# Spring noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to set up my Spring MVC testing environment. 
But I always get this **noHandlerFound** error:

Aug 21, 2014 4:43:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restful/firstPage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Aug 21, 2014 4:47:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restful/firstPage2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Aug 21, 2014 5:10:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restful/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

I already searched for solution, but none can fix my problem.

My spring mvc version: 3.1.3.RELEASE

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

this is my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

this is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="test.spring" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/index.html" location="/index.html" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/firstPage" />
```

This is my Controller:

```
package test.spring;
....
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FirstController {  
@RequestMapping(value = "firstPage2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFirstPage(Map<String,Object> model){
    return "firstPage";     
    }
}
```

My server is tomcat 7, there is no error and warning when it is deployed.
I also tried this with no luck:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Before I start Spring MVC, I can access index.html

Comment: You should always keep your controller/servlet config in the servlet context, ie. `spring-servlet.xml` in your case.

Comment: you are right, I move everything from applicationContext.xml into spring-servlet.xml, now it works.